# Swift json decoding fails when data is empty in function with generic types

Tags: swift, generics, jsondecoder

I have written a function with generic type result.

```
private func fetch<Request, Response>(_ endpoint: Types.EndPoint,
                                          method: HTTPMethod = .get,
                                          body: Request? = nil,
                                          then callback: ((Result<Response, Types.Error>) -> Void)? = nil
    ) where Request: Encodable, Response: Decodable {

    //Network request creation...

    let dataTask = URLSession.shared
            .dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Fetch error: \(error)")
                    callback?(.failure(.generic(reason: "Could not fetch data :\(error.localizedDescription)")))
                } else {
                                            
                    if let data = data {


                        do {
                            let result = try self.decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data) // **exception here**
                            callback?(.success(result))
                        } catch {
                            print("Decoding error: \(error)")
                            callback?(.failure(.generic(reason: "Could not decode data :\(error.localizedDescription)")))
                        }

                    }
                }
    }
}


......

apiClient.fetch(.updateUser, API.Types.Request.User) { (result: Result<API.Types.Response.Empty, API.Types.Error>) in
        
        //handle result
        
}
```

API.Types.Response.Empty is a struct,

```
struct Empty: Decodable {}
```

Now my question is, when above api is called, server returns an empty response (`Content-Length` is `0`) when it is successful. (`status-code` is `200`). only few apis do this, other apis return some kind of json with the response.

When response data is empty, json decoding throws an exception

```
Unable to parse empty data." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to parse empty data
```

How do I properly handle this situation? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just check if data is empty and response status is 200 before trying to decode it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because empty data is not a valid JSON. Here's a simple test:

```
struct Empty: Codable {}
var data = Data()
// or var data = "".data(using: .utf8)!
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Empty.self, from: data)
```

will throw the same exception, and it actually contains the explanation:

```
DecodingError
  ▿ dataCorrupted : Context
    - codingPath : 0 elements
    - debugDescription : "The given data was not valid JSON."
    ▿ underlyingError : Optional<Error>
      - some : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to parse empty data." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to parse empty data.}
```

The valid JSON data that matches your model would look like `{}` (i.e. an object with no fields). This works:

```
var data = "{}".data(using: .utf8)! // <-- empty JSON object
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Empty.self, from: data)
```

So next question is: is it your fault or API fault, and can you fix it by properly using the information in the headers:

1. Are you always sending `Accept: application/json` header with your request?

   - if yes, clearly API doesn't respect it. It may be an API bug, unless API docs tell you to do something else (see point 2.)
   - if not, you may need to start sending it to tell the API to always send JSON back.
2. When your API returns an empty data, what does it specify in `content-type` header?

   - If API still claims that it returned `application/json`, it's a bug in API.
   - If API sets `content-type` to something different in this case, not `application/json`, then you need to get this header from response (`response.contentType`) and parse it differently.

If neither of the above options is available, then you have to do a workaround and just check if data size is 0. But that's suboptimal, because you are relying on some behaviour of the API, which may or may not be accidental.

Comment: 1. Yes, Accept: application/json is always sent
2. content-type says application/json even when it returns empty data.

API is still being developed by a party that i don't have any direct contact with, so for the time being, I may have to use a workaround as you suggested. I was having trouble on how to create a Data object that matches the Empty struct. I did not realise that it needs to be an empty json. So thanks for pointing it out for me!

Answer (score 3):

`Data` has an `isEmpty` property that you can use so if this is true and then you need to check if the Response type is correct for this

```
if let data = data {
    if data.isEmpty {
        if Response.self == Empty.self {
            callback(.success(Empty()))
        } else {
            callback(.failure(<data was unexpectedly empty>))
        }
    } else if Response.self == Empty.self {
        // You have data but I guess it can't be decoded properly in this case
        callback(.failure(<data wasn't empty>))
    }
    // otherwise decode as before...
}
```